# Conditional Expectation of linear combination of Normal Random Variable

Tags: probability

I have a problem on this question about conditional expectation.

Suppose $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1)$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
 $\rho(x,y) = -0.72$. Compute $\mathbb{E}(3X+Y|X-Y=1)$.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: What is $\rho(x,y)$, the correlation between x and y?

Comment: Yes, $\rho$ is the correlation between two random variables @BlackMath

Comment: The question is wrongly stated.  If the random variables are independent the covariance cannot be $-0.72$

Comment: What does the chapter on gaussian families in your course, say about this?

Comment: As mentioned, two RVs cannot be independent and the correlation between them is not 0.

Comment: It's a quant interview question I come across @Did

Comment: OK, and when preparing for it, you used some texts, right? What did these say about gaussian families?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. This is a question that I encountered when I having my quant interview with a company. @Did

Comment: Yes, you already told us that, but you keep avoiding answering my specific query -- which may be seen as indicative of your approach to the site.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Do you mean sum of two normally distributed random variable is still normally distributed?@Did

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2912570/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are NOT independent but are jointly normal  here is my answer: the penultimate step in your calculation is wrong. You can find the conditional expectation as follows: choose a value of $c$ such that the covariance of $3X+Y+c(X-Y)$ and $X-Y$ is $0$. (I will leave it to you to compute the covariance and solve for $c$). By joint normality this makes these two random variables independent. Then $$E [(3X+Y|X-Y=1)=E (3X+Y+c(X-Y)]|X-Y=1)$$ $$-E(c(X-Y)|X-Y=1)=0-c=-c$$.

[I have used the fact that (by independence)  $E[(3X+Y+c(X-Y)]|X-Y=1)=E (3X+Y+c(X-Y)]=0$].